# php casting variable to array

Tags: php, arrays, casting

I am dealing with very strange issue of dealing with garbage in iterating through variable which has been cast to an array

```
$arr = (array)$var; // problem
$arr = array($var); // ok
```

The first method seems to work fine on values with integers, but not with strings. Is there any documented difference and does php have `real` casting ?

---

The problem is with lavarel 4, [Database sources](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L704), function on line 704

Comment: Can you say what $var's value for two example?

Comment: The second thing is not typecasting, you are creating an one element array, and the element's value is $var.

Comment: This is a PHP bug - fixed in PHP 5.2.7 and higher. What version do you use?

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ as I mentioned - integer and string, this results in different behaviour

Comment: @Tyralcori php --version - PHP 5.4.28

Comment: Your problem cannot be repoduced: http://ideone.com/cnkOqV

Comment: @hindmost well, as with most scripting language examples it shows only in complicated enviroments

Comment: @Tyralcori This is the first time I heard about it. Can you provide any proof?

Comment: @Ulterior So you have to provide the details about your enviroment. Otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: A first step to provide more information could be to tell us what `garbage` is. And what the input value is that provides this `garbage`.

Comment: @enricog by garbage I mean parts of some sort of strings from memory which definetly are not part of the variable data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$var` is a scalar, it's documented that both lines do the same:

> For any of the types: integer, float, string, boolean and resource, converting a value to an array results in an array with a single element with index zero and the value of the scalar which was converted. In other words, **(array)$scalarValue is exactly the same as array($scalarValue)**.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Comment: so that means thats a bug, I would expect this functionality

Comment: @Ulterior: yes, if you've got a reproducible error case, feel free to file it at bugs.php.net. Both lines must do the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to cast a variable in PHP as a specific type.

1. using the settype() function
2. using (int) (bool) (float) etc

More Info : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/type-casting-php/

Comment: settype results in same garbage on iterating through an array